# OpenSSL не принимает закрытый ключ

Tags: php, веб-программирование, openssl, криптография

Нужно считать закрытый ключ из файла для дальнейшей работы с ним, использую PHP скрипт следующего содержания:

```
$pk = openssl_pkey_get_private("file:///var/www/html/secure/private_key.pem");
if($pk === false){
    echo "openssl_pkey_get_private error: ".openssl_error_string()."<br>";
} else {
    echo "success.<br>";
}
```

Выводит следующее:

> openssl_pkey_get_private error: error:0906D066:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad end line.

Файл генерирую вот так: "openssl genrsa -out C:\openssl\private_key.pem 2048". Пробовал перегенерировать файл, пробовал вставить его содержимое в переменную. Путь до файла рабочий.
Содержимое файла:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEArRVWiqjtWpKMbYhQMqJCYdr0sM+R/Z32Vk7BthWsCioirLTw
...
dKCiphrYWrxo1IJ+YITnRx+xh0xz5dzUP4z0XhEd0TdtynHsjk1P7A==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

В чём может быть проблема? Из-за чего "плохой конец"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в отсутствии прав доступа на запуск у файла, после их установки всё заработало.